# Can I use Spacy for noun classification?

Tags: spacy

People use Spacy for detecting Named Entities (proper nouns) in piece of text. I am wondering whether one can use Spacy to detect and classify nouns instead of Proper Nouns. If we train with a noun classification dataset, will the same algorithm works?

Comment: Looking through documentation there is a pos for noun once tokenized. https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Each token has an associated Part of Speech (pos) tag. The POS for each token can be accessed using the `token.pos_` attribute.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("My name is Chaithanya. I have a book, a pen, an eraser and a pencil on me. ")

for token in doc:
  if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
    print(token.text, token.pos_)
```

**Output**:

```
name NOUN
book NOUN
pen NOUN
eraser NOUN
pencil NOUN
```

Comment: Thanks but my question can I use Spacy to further classify Nouns. Say I have two categories of Nouns - Writing Nouns ( pen, pencil in this example), Other Nouns. If I have text along with the labels as Nouns and Other Nouns, can I use the text to train and create a model and then predict writing nouns and other nouns instead of just nouns by using spacy? I want to use training sample code (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py) to train and save the model. Use the saved model to detect Writing Nouns and other Nouns.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can. The documentation has detailed examples [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-tagger).